# creation of database through ODBC takes a very long time in sql server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

i am exporting a datasheet from access into sql server 2008. it exports it fine, but it takes a very long amount of time for me to actually see it in SSMS. does anyone know why it takes so long? i dont know how long it takes because it's been about 10 minutes, but i do know that it was created since i was trying to export the same thing again and it says that it already exists there. my database is only a few megabytes

Comment: How are you accomplishing the export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of a guess, but are you expecting to see the table in the Object Explorer tree in SSMS?

The lists of objects shown in Object Explorer are built the first time the data is viewed cached and do not auto-refresh.

You can update the list by right-clicking on the parent node (in this case, "Tables") and selecting "refresh".

A more reliable guide to whether the table exists will be to attempt to select from it, or examining the DB metadata using a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_name = 'your_table_name'
```